# WPF Datagrid comboboxcolumn with checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in WPF bound to an ObservableCollection wich I read/save in a XML File. I'd now like to add a comboboxcolumn with checkboxes or something similar. 
There should be a dropdown menu for selecting one or more weekdays.

Does anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

After implementing christoph's custom control(DropDownDayPicker), I could bind my data to it, but not in the other way(get the updated value(s) if it changes)
So here's what I tried:

My Object:
Entry.cs

```
public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Id;
    string ExecuteOn;
}
```

MyWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<Entry> entryList;

        doc.Load("C:\\test\\list.xml");
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Entry");
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            XmlNodeList subnodes = node.SelectNodes("ExecuteOn");
            ObservableCollection<Weekday> days = new ObservableCollection<Weekday>();
            foreach(XmlNode subnode in node["ExecuteOn"].ChildNodes)
                days.Add( (Weekday)Enum.Parse(typeof(Weekday),subnode.InnerText));

            _entryList.Add(new Entry(
                node["Id"].InnerText, 
                node["Description"].InnerText, 
                node["Path"].InnerText, 
                Convert.ToInt32(node["KindOfTask"].InnerText), 
                days
                ));
        }
```

MyWindow.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="EntryView" ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding EntryList}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="false" Margin="0,34,0,37" CanUserAddRows="false" Height="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Days" x:Name="cellExecuteOn" Width="*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:DropDownDayPicker SelectedWeekdays="{Binding ExecuteOn}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here's what the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfEntry>
  <Entry>
    <Id>efbae4da-f833-4d07-a8af-9ec3421b4886</Id>
    <ExecuteOn>
      <Weekday>Montag</Weekday>
      <Weekday>Dienstag</Weekday>
    </ExecuteOn>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <Id>1cb13340-40dd-48c1-ada5-bbb6f79c0d06</Id>
    <ExecuteOn>
      <Weekday>Montag</Weekday>
    </ExecuteOn>
  </Entry>
</ArrayOfEntry>
```

Comment: Well your `Entry` class seems to be incomplete, but what is obviously is that you have fields in it and no properties. Binding works only with properties not with fields. I prepare a little binding sample on that and update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Try something like this:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox Content="Monday"/>
                            <CheckBox Content="Friday"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Hope that suits your needs.

**Update:**
Ok, now the professional approach. I made a custom control for what you want. (Please don´t rate the look, you can customize it). Here comes the code...

**Weekday.cs**

```
public enum Weekday
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

**DropDownDayPicker.cs**

```
public class DropDownDayPicker : Control
{
    private List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();

    static DropDownDayPicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DropDownDayPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DropDownDayPicker)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        StackPanel weekdayBoxes = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_weekdayHost") as StackPanel;

        foreach(CheckBox box in weekdayBoxes.Children)
        {
            box.Checked += Box_CheckedChanged;
            box.Unchecked += Box_CheckedChanged;
            this.checkboxes.Add(box);
        }

        Button openPopup = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_openPopupButton") as Button;
        openPopup.Click += OpenPopup_Click;

        this.UpdateCheckboxes();
    }

    private void OpenPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_popup") as Popup;
        popup.IsOpen = !popup.IsOpen;

    }

    private void Box_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateSelectedWeekdays();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Weekday> SelectedWeekdays
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Weekday>)GetValue(SelectedWeekdaysProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedWeekdaysProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedWeekdaysProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedWeekdays", typeof(ObservableCollection<Weekday>), typeof(DropDownDayPicker), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Weekday>(), SelectedWeekdaysPropertyChanged));

    private static void SelectedWeekdaysPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        DropDownDayPicker picker = sender as DropDownDayPicker;
        ObservableCollection<Weekday> oldValue = args.OldValue as ObservableCollection<Weekday>;
        ObservableCollection<Weekday> newValue = args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<Weekday>;

        if (picker != null)
        {
            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                oldValue.CollectionChanged -= picker.SelectedWeekdaysChanged;
            }

            if (newValue != null)
            {
                newValue.CollectionChanged += picker.SelectedWeekdaysChanged;
            }

            picker.UpdateCheckboxes();
        }
    }

    private void SelectedWeekdaysChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateCheckboxes();
    }

    private bool updating = false;

    private void UpdateCheckboxes()
    {
        if (!this.updating)
        {
            this.updating = true;
            if (this.SelectedWeekdays != null)
            {
                foreach (CheckBox box in this.checkboxes)
                {
                    box.IsChecked = this.SelectedWeekdays.Contains((Weekday)box.Tag);
                }
            }
            this.UpdateSummary();
            this.updating = false;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSelectedWeekdays()
    {
        if (!this.updating)
        {
            this.updating = true;
            var selectedWeekdays = this.checkboxes.Where(x => x.IsChecked.HasValue && x.IsChecked.Value).Select(x => x.Tag).Cast<Weekday>();
            this.SelectedWeekdays = new ObservableCollection<Weekday>(selectedWeekdays);
            this.UpdateSummary();
            this.updating = false;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSummary()
    {
        TextBlock summary = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_summary") as TextBlock;
        if (this.SelectedWeekdays != null)
        {                
            if (this.SelectedWeekdays.Count == 0)
            {
                summary.Text = "none";
            }
            else if (this.SelectedWeekdays.Count == 1)
            {
                summary.Text = this.SelectedWeekdays[0].ToString();
            }
            else if (this.SelectedWeekdays.Count > 1)
            {
                summary.Text = string.Format("{0} days",this.SelectedWeekdays.Count);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            summary.Text = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

**in Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DropDownDayPicker}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="PART_openPopupButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" x:Name="PART_summary"/>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Text="&#xE0E5;" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_openPopupButton}" IsOpen="False" x:Name="PART_popup" StaysOpen="False">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="PART_weekdayHost" Background="White">
                        <CheckBox Content="Monday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Monday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Thusday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Tuesday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Wednesday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Wednesday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Thursday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                    <local:Weekday>Thursday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Friday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Friday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Saturday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Saturday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Sunday">
                            <CheckBox.Tag>
                                <local:Weekday>Sunday</local:Weekday>
                            </CheckBox.Tag>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
</Style>
```

**and the datagrid**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:DropDownDayPicker SelectedWeekdays="{Binding whatEver}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I know this is pretty much effort but that is the way I would do it in a real world scenario.

**Update 2:**
I tried making a sample for you and noticed there is a small mistake I made. Please see DropDownDayPicker.cs and update method `UpdateSelectedWeekdays` like this:

```
    private void UpdateSelectedWeekdays()
    {
        if (!this.updating)
        {
            this.updating = true;
            var selectedWeekdays = this.checkboxes.Where(x => x.IsChecked.HasValue && x.IsChecked.Value).Select(x => x.Tag).Cast<Weekday>();

            SetCurrentValue(DropDownDayPicker.SelectedWeekdaysProperty, new ObservableCollection<Weekday>(selectedWeekdays));
            BindingExpression binding = this.GetBindingExpression(DropDownDayPicker.SelectedWeekdaysProperty);
            if (binding != null)
            {
                binding.UpdateSource();
            }

            this.UpdateSummary();
            this.updating = false;
        }
    }
```

So with that corrected lets come to the sample code.

**Entry.cs**

```
public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Weekday> days = new ObservableCollection<Weekday>();
    public ObservableCollection<Weekday> Days
    {
        get { return days; }
        set { days = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Days"); }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Viewmodel.cs**

```
public class Viewmodel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Entry> collection = new ObservableCollection<Entry>()
    {
        new Entry() { Title = "Entry 1" },
        new Entry() { Title = "Entry 2" },
        new Entry() { Title = "Entry 3" }
    };
    public ObservableCollection<Entry> Collection
    {
        get { return collection; }
        set { collection = value; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Viewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Days">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:DropDownDayPicker SelectedWeekdays="{Binding Days, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Collection[0].Days.Count}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now when changing the days of the first row you see the count of selected days beneath the datagrid. Notice that the default binding mode of the selected days is OneWay. You have to assign `Mode=TwoWay` in order to make it working.

Try it out and give me some feedback.

Comment: Not realy. I need a dropdown.

Comment: I see, okay I will prepare a solution. That will take a couple of minutes because a ComboBox would not be the right thing.

Comment: @CE made another approach. Have a look at it.

Comment: great thx! The custom control works on it's own, but I have problems binding my Data to the control.

Comment: No Problem, Post your viewmodel and let me take a look.

Comment: The updated UpdateSelectedWeekdays made the trick! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what christoph had you can implement a combobox with something like this

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Week Days">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"/>   
                            <CheckBox/>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Where Days is an enum property in a ObservableCollection of that class

```
 public class SomeData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Days Days { get; set; }

}

 public enum Days
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;          
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SomeData> SomeCollection { get; set; }

}
```

Here is a good resource to learn about wpf datagrids
[Datagrid tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)